# LITTERATURE SEARCH: Linear model on Vector space

Tags: references, linear-model, linear-algebra

I need a reference to an abstract treatment of the linear model on a space V where X is a  normal variable (on V) with mean in a subspace of V, where all key results are given in this abstract framework, like how the estimate of the mean is the orthogonal projection of X onto the subspace containing the mean and so on.

Comment: See also the related:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2730/good-resource-to-understand-anova-and-ancova,   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190250/bibliography-for-linear-models, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/414/introduction-to-statistics-for-mathematicians

Answer (score 1):

Books that fit your requirements:

[The Coordinate-Free Approach to Linear Models](https://bookshop.org/books/the-coordinate-free-approach-to-linear-models/9780521868426) by Michael J. Wichura.

[Multivariate Statistics: A Vector Space Approach](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/institute-of-mathematical-statistics-lecture-notes-monograph-series/Multivariate-Statistics/toc/10.1214/lnms/1196285102) by Morris L. Eaton